# Show certain posts in a LIST format that members have been granted access to

Tags: posts, blog, list, private

I need post visibility control, but I don't want just "a class of users" to be able to see a post; I want just 2 or 3 users I specify to see a post. Then later, those same users will go on to view other posts they are assigned to, but here's the kicker...those 2 or 3 users that could view the specific post I assigned them to...? They are not going to be a group that stays together. Each user in that group will be able to see other specific posts I assign them to at later dates, and will each be part of other groups that are given permission to view a specific post.

Can CSS or a plugin drill down privacy to be THAT specific and flexible? The plugin I use now ("WP JV Post Reading Groups") does half that job -- can assign users to read specific posts. Which is great. But each user can't see a list of posts that they have access to without seeing ALL POSTS on the site (when I give them permission to see private posts then they see ALL private posts which I do not want) -- which will be a mess since there will be A LOT of posts.

I don't want users to have to sift through mountains of posts they can't get to; I want them to not even know other posts they're not allowed to read EVEN EXIST. I do not want them to be able to see a post they can't click on and read. And I want the individual specific posts they are given specific permission to see to be displayed in a list called, "Posts" -- that's a page I've created to propagate for all users. The only difference is that each user will ONLY SEE POSTS THEY HAVE BEEN GIVEN individual, specific permission to see -- listed there on that page.

Here's what I've posted elsewhere...a longer explanation:

So, nothing is broken on my site; this is basically a general question. I've googled, looked in StackOverflow, and racked my brain at how this could possibly be done. Nothing I've found seems to fit my needs.

I'm looking for a solution that will restrict specific members from seeing specific post content....but to an extent that doesn't seem to be common.

Example:

1. Member A signs up to read my blog.
2. Member B signs up to read my blog.
3. I create a page called, "Posts" that is based on the blog template, where all blog posts are listed.
4. I create 6 blog posts. All marked as "private" in view settings, so these posts do not come up in search. But they can display on the "Posts" page I have created, in a list format.
5. I can give permissions on each post via a plugin called, "WP JV Post Reading Groups" for specific members to read specific posts, via creating "reading groups" that I add members to. So now I give Member A permission to view posts 1, 2, and 3. I give permissions to view posts 4, 5, and 6 to Member B.
6. In the page I created to list blog posts....keep in mind that each post I make is listed there. BUT I do not want the posts I designated as "viewable" to Member A to appear to Member B in the list of posts to click on. I want these posts to essentially be invisible to others that cannot read them. Not just in content, but in listing of each post alongside each other.

The plugin I'm using to restrict viewability to certain members works great -- if you always have the direct link handy. They can read content of a private post...but they cannot see that very same post they have permission to read come up in search. Or mentioned in a list of posts they have access to.

Specific members with view permissions on specific posts works.

But it does not allow a private post to be viewable in the listing of available posts to read for those particular members -- it only allows those specific members to view a specific post's CONTENT.

Not its listing.

I'm willing to ditch the plugin I'm using or do WHATEVERRR it takes, lol, to accomplish my goal. Just please let me know if there is a PHP or CSS workaround, or even a better plugin to accomplish this.

Thoughts?

**Note: the user should not even be able to see any content they're not allowed to see -- so they would not even be able to click on it. The only posts they should see in a list of "latest blog posts" is content that they have permission to see.

All other content they do not have permission to see would be invisible to them -- as if that content does not even exist.

***P.S.: this site will accommodate 1,000 users very soon -- perhaps within the next 6 months...and will assuredly accommodate 10,000 users within the year

Each post will be unique to the group of users I assign it to...never to be used again

SO general permissions are not the way to go; I need to find a way to assign unique permissions to a few users to one specific blog post

Those same users will EACH be part of other groups that do not include members of the group they were in when they all read that first blog post

The plugin I'm using -- "WP JV Post Reading Groups" -- is great at specifying which users can view which posts. I can create a post, assign usernames that have permission to read the post, then mark the post as "Private" and only those users can see it...BUT I have to give those users the direct link....which is bound to cause chaos in the future if/when they lose that direct link; they then have to contact customer support and etc....a hassle

Comment: P.S.: if I do not give that user class permissions to view private posts...and they are just a subscriber, then when they go to the "Posts" page they seeeee....nothing. LOL. The plugin requires that posts visibility are set to "Private" to work. But that means you can't see the list of posts on the page I've created for posts to display.......unless you have permissions to view all private posts. Which then means users can view ALL private posts -- not just the ones they're assigned to, LOL....UGH.

Comment: You could accomplish what you want with a custom plugin or set of functions, and the goal doesn't present any steep coding challenges. Depending on other aspects of the desire implementation, the goal might also be facilitated by an advanced membership and access-control plugin like S2Member. Either way, completing the application would be somewhat time-consuming, even if it doesn't present any obvious steep coding or conceptual challenges.